# full page scrolling with sticky header

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make a full page scrolling using css in react but the issues comes with the sticky header. As the section had height of 100vh so it take all that space and by having header with z-index 999 it stays on the top but section area comes under it. what i'am trying to do is that header remains on the top but the section starts below that header not under it. here my code css code and here the link to github [github link](https://github.com/Faizan98x/knox.git)

```
.scroll-section{
  min-height: 80vh;
  padding: 8rem 0;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) can help you

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can achieve a sticky header, with a combination of CSS and JS.

I'm leaving here a link to one Codepen I personally used in the past as inspiration (this is not made by me, I used it to create my own):

Link: https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/ZEBbeP

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="header-banner">
        <h1>Visit Finland</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <nav>
        <div class="site-title">Finland</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <ul>
   </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
/* resets */
body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

/* main */
header {
height: 360px;
z-index: 10;
}
.header-banner {
background-color: #333;
background-image: url('https://37.media.tumblr.com/8b4969985e84b2aa1ac8d3449475f1af/tumblr_n3iftvUesn1snvqtdo1_1280.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}

header h1 {
background-color: rgba(18,72,120, 0.8);
color: #fff;
padding: 0 1rem;
position: absolute;
top: 2rem; 
left: 2rem;
}

.fixed-header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%; 
}

nav {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: #292f36;
postion: fixed;
z-index: 10;
}

nav div {
color: white;
font-size: 2rem;
line-height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 2%;
visibility: hidden;
}
.visible-title {
visibility: visible;
}

nav ul { 
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 2% auto 0;
padding-left: 0;
text-align: right;
max-width: 100%;
}
nav ul li { 
display: inline-block; 
line-height: 60px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none; 
color: #a9abae;
}
```

JS:

```
/* ========================================== 
scrollTop() >= 300
Should be equal the the height of the header
========================================== */

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
    $('nav div').addClass('visible-title');
}
else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
    $('nav div').removeClass('visible-title');
}
});
```

I've only included the header's code which is the one doing the magic, but you'll find the complete one in the link I pasted above.

Hope this helps. :)